# "Buy not only seasonal and local but also seeded produce." Is this sentence grammatically okay?

Tags: usage

Just one sentence.

"Buy not only seasonal and local but also seeded produce." Is this sentence grammatically okay?

Do you use this structure 'not only A and B but also C'?

Comment: I think the context you added in your comments should be placed in the question by editing.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence using the structure

> not only A and B but also C

is grammatically correct, but doesn't really make sense in meaning.

What do you mean by "***seeded***"?

Comment: I read 'seeded fruits and vegetables' from a passage. Doesn't it make sense, either?

Comment: "If you have the choice, avoid fruits that are 'seedless" when you know they would naturally have seeds. A seedless fruit or vegetable is not in its natural state and has less energy than a natural fruit or vegetable. Look for or grow fruits and vegetables that contain seeds. If you buy your produce at a natural foods store, ask the produce manager if they could please order some seeded fruits and vegetables." - source : Sunfood Living: Resource Guide for Global Health
By John McCabe

Comment: Notice how the example provides context that allows the reader to understand the invented expression "seeded fruit".